# Inserting Data and retrieving the Primary key at the same time. Through 1 submit Only PHP, MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a registration part where the form collects the personal and educational information of the user. This will be saved into 2 different tables.

***tblPersonal*** (userId, first_name, last_name, gender, username, password, email)

1. First name = $first_name
2. Last name = $last_name
3. gender = $gender
4. username = $applicantusername
5. password = $pwd
6. Email = $email

***tblEducational*** (educ_id, userId, school, school_type)

7. School description = $school
8. Type = $schooltype

The userId located from *tblEducational* is a foreign key coming from *tblPersonal*.

When the user fills up the form. The data will automatically save to these 2 different table. This should be done on a single submission.

The userId is **AUTO_INCREMENT** and will be created only when the data is inserted to the tblPersonal.

**Problem:**

*(userId will be used to classify who's the person studied of a specific school)*

How can I get the userId

When the data of *tblPersonal* and *tblEducational* should be inserted at the same time?

```
include("../../private/pdo-conn.php");
 try
{
   $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
   $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $query = "INSERT INTO tblPersonal VALUES('','$first_name','$last_name','$gender','$applicantusername','$pwd','$email')";
     $data = $connect->query($query);

     //Query for inserting data into tblEducational??
     //INSERT INTO tblEducational VALUES('',??,'$school','$schooltype'); My Idea, different query.
     header("location: registration.php?success=true");
 }
catch(PDOException $error)
 {
 $error->getMessage();
 }
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: Maybe my question quiet simple for those professional. Beginner here. Thank you!!